# Using MQTT to update Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter, mqtt

I have a virtual light bulb (Tkinter GUI), I have two separate images for if the bulb is on or off. I am trying to figure out how I can use MQTT (paho mqtt) to turn this virtual bulb on or off. I am able to publish and subscirbe to topics, and I can use the received message ("On" or "Off") to determine which image to display, I just cannot figure out how to update this when a new message is received.

This is where I am creating the Tkinter GUI

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import sys

root = Tk()
root.geometry("768x1024")

if sys.argv[1]:
    if sys.argv[1] == "On":
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("light-on.jpg"))
    else:
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("light-off.jpg"))

panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()
```

And this is where I am subscribing to the topic and retrieving messages.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt #import the client1
import time
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
import random

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("message received " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    print("message topic=",message.topic)
    print("message qos=",message.qos)
    print("message retain flag=",message.retain)
    subprocess.call(['./pythongui.py',message.payload.decode()])

broker_address="test.mosquitto.org"

print("creating new instance")
client = mqtt.Client() #create new instance
client.on_message=on_message #attach function to callback

print("connecting to broker")
client.connect(broker_address) #connect to broker

print("Subscribing to topic","house/bulbs/bulb1")
client.subscribe("house/bulbs/bulb1")

client.loop_forever()
```

I am aware that I probably shouldn't be creating a subprocess and this is probably completely wrong but I cannot figure out how to do this. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Which one of the scripts you have need fixing, both or only one? If it's only one, then which one?(I can attempt to help if it's the [tag:tkinter] one only)

Comment: Both kind of, basically I just want to know that if I have the tkinter script running, is there a way to edit the gui live and change the image from another script?

Comment: It _may_ be possible to do that using the internal reference names of the GUI widgets in the Tcl interpreter tkinter uses but I'd doubt that would be considered good practice even if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
##! /usr/bin/python3
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt #import the client1
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

#Get the window and set the size
window = Tk()
window.geometry('320x200')

#Load both the images
img_on = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("light-on.jpg"))
img_off = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('light-off.jpg'))

panel = Label(window, image = img_on)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

# This is the event handler method that receives the Mosquito messages
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    msg = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    print("message received " , msg)

    #If the received message is light on then set the image the the ‘light on’ image
    if msg == "Study/HUE_STATE/on":
        panel.configure(image=img_on)
        print("****ON")
        panel.update()
    #If the received message is light off then set the image the the ‘light off’ image
    elif msg == "Study/HUE_STATE/off":
        panel.configure(image=img_off)
        print("****OFF")         
        panel.update()

broker_address="test.mosquitto.org"

print("creating new instance")
client = mqtt.Client() #create new instance
client.on_message=on_message #attach function to callback

print("connecting to broker")
client.connect(broker_address) #connect to broker

print("Subscribing to topic","home")
client.subscribe("home")

 #Start the MQTT Mosquito process loop
client.loop_start() 

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Appreciate this is quite an old post, however for completeness ... the code above should do the job.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link under the answer to add some explanation of how this works.